# transform typescript import statement into string with file contents through tsc

Tags: typescript, import, transpiler

I am looking for a solution to import a text file into a typescript module by doing:

```
import textfile as './assets/text.txt';
```

I have already declared a module with `declare module "*.txt"` and then exporting a string, but whenever running `tsc`, the output is not transpiled into

```
const textfile = 'contents of file'
```

So I was wondering about what are the current alternatives for transforming the import statement into a string constant without having to use babel, webpack, rollup, etc?

I was previously reading about `ttypescript` with `ttsc` but I'm not sure it is still a good option with Typescript 4.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just use the node fs module?

Comment: @aminits, I was looking into distributing the module as a single file which would ideally be compatible with node and the browser. Wouldn't that be a problem?